# Solving a $4\times 4$ linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I was given the following problem and asked to solve for all the unknowns.

> Solve for $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$: 
>   $$
> \begin{matrix}
> x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=1,\\
> x_1+x_2-x_3=2,\\
> x_2+x_3=0 
> \end{matrix}
> $$

---

There are $4$ unknowns and $3$ equations. So isn't it not possible to get a single solution?

And every time I try to manipulate the equations, I keep on getting identity equations such as $$2=2$$

Comment: $(1,0.5,-0.5,0)$ is one of the infinitely many solutions to this system of equations

Comment: are they integers?

Comment: Why the down vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

You're right. This system doesn't have a unique solution. Indeed it has infinitely many. Write the system, for example, as $$\left\{\begin{align}x_1+x_2+x_3& =1-x_4\\x_1+x_2-x_3 & =2\\x_2+x_3& =0\end{align}\right.$$ and solve it for $x_1,x_2,x_3.$ The solutions will depend on $x_4.$ For each value of $x_4$ you have a different solution.

Comment: following on from this, we can get a general solution as $(1-\alpha,\frac{\alpha+1}{2},-\frac{\alpha+1}{2},\alpha)$, which has infinitely many integral solutions for odd $\alpha$

Answer (score 0):

you can take the solve variable as $$x_2,x_3,x_4$$ and the solution is given by $$\left\{\left\{x_2\to 1-\frac{x_1}{2},x_3\to
   \frac{x_1}{2}-1,x_4\to 1-x_1\right\}\right\}$$ and $x_1$ is a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

By eliminating the third row, you have
$$
\begin{cases}x_1+x_4=1
\\x_1+2x_2=2.
\end{cases}
$$
By simple observation, the solution can not be unique.

Now for the question regarding finding all the solutions to the system, do you know [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination)? What systematic method have you learned for solving linear equations?

Comment: I have not learned Gaussian elimination. But I have learned substitution and elimination in general.